# How to return a value from the while/for loop in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a newbie in Scala. I want to read data from Oracle database in each Spark Node and convert it to Spark DataFrame. The code is in following:

```
 def read_data(group_id: Int):String =  {
   val table_name = "table"
   val col_name = "col"
   val query =
  """ select f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8
    | from """.stripMargin + table_name + """ where MOD(TO_NUMBER(substr("""+col_name+""", -LEAST(2, LENGTH("""+col_name+""")))),"""+num_node+""")="""+group_id
   val oracleUser = "ORCL"
   val oraclePassword = "*******"
   val oracleURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//x.x.x.x:1521/ORCLDB"
   val ods = new OracleDataSource()
   ods.setUser(oracleUser)
   ods.setURL(oracleURL)
   ods.setPassword(oraclePassword)
   val con = ods.getConnection()
   val statement = con.createStatement()
   statement.setFetchSize(1000)      // important
   val  resultSet : java.sql.ResultSet = statement.executeQuery(query) 

   var ret = " "
   while(resultSet.next()) {
     for {i <- 1 until 8 by 1
        ret = ret.concat(resultSet.getString(i))
        ret = ret.concat(" ")
      }yield(ret)
     return ret
    }
   println("ret:",ret)
   return ret
   }

val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("local[2]")
  .setAppName("testScala")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
  .set("spark.executor.cores", "2")
  .set("spark.task.cpus","1")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
 val rdd = sc.parallelize(group_list,num_node)
      .map(read_data).map(x => println(x)).count()
 println("rdd:",rdd)
```

The part of the code that I have problem is in the following:

```
  var ret = " "
 while(resultSet.next()) {
  for (i <- 1 until 8 by 1) {
      ret = ret.concat(resultSet.getString(i))
      ret = ret.concat(" ")
    return ret
  }
  return ret
}
println("ret:",ret)
```

`println("ret:",ret)` print `null` string. When I change the code like this:

```
 var ret = " "
while(resultSet.next()) {
  for {i <- 1 until 8 by 1
      ret = ret.concat(resultSet.getString(i))
      ret = ret.concat(" ")
  }yield(ret)
  return ret
}
```

I receive this error:

```
ret is already defined as value ret
      ret = ret.concat(" ")
```

In fact, before running, I see that code has problem with `concat`:

```
Cannot resolve symbol concat
```

Would you please guide me how I can access result of `while/for` outside them?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are trying to do. What is the type of `resultSet` and what is your expected output?

Comment: @JarrodBaker, I update my question. Would you please take a look at it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace your code

```
 var ret = " "
while(resultSet.next()) {
  for {i <- 1 until 8 by 1
      ret = ret.concat(resultSet.getString(i))
      ret = ret.concat(" ")
  }yield(ret)
  return ret
}
```

by

```
val ret = Iterator.continually(resultSet)
                  .takeWhile(_.next)
                  .flatMap(r => (1 until 8).map(i => r.getString(i)))
                  .mkString(" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using for-comprehension here. What you actually do here is creating a new val called `ret`. What you write is evaluated as

```
for(i <- 1 until 8 by 1){
  val ret = ret.concat(resultSet.getString(i))
  val ret = ret.concat(" ")
 } yield(ret)
```

What you can do instead is usage of

```
  for {i <- 1 until 8 by 1
      _ = ret = ret.concat(resultSet.getString(i))
      _ = ret = ret.concat(" ")
  } yield(ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using for-comprehension here. What you actually do here is creating a new val called `ret`. What you write is evaluated as

```
for(i <- 1 until 8 by 1){
  val ret = ret.concat(resultSet.getString(i))
  val ret = ret.concat(" ")
 } yield(ret)
```

What you can do instead is usage of

```
  for {i <- 1 until 8 by 1
      _ = ret = ret.concat(resultSet.getString(i))
      _ = ret = ret.concat(" ")
  } yield(ret)
```

Or to simplify the whole loop replace it with the following (I'm not sure what's your intent with that code, I assume you want to have whole concanated string `ret`, however by usage of `yield` I would assume you also want the intermediate steps of this process)

```
   val ret = new StringBuilder(" ")
   var steps: Seq[String] = Nil 
   while(resultSet.next()) {
     steps = { 
       for (i <- 1 until 8 by 1) {
        ret = ret.append(resultSet.getString(i)).append(" ")
        } yield(ret.toString)
      }
    }
```

Comment: You have two answers, probably you wanted to edit the other one instead (I upvoted it so you don't lose reputation if you do that).